# How do I use multivariable functions in sympy?

Tags: python, function, sympy

I was trying to evaluate a multivariable function at a couple of inputs but for some weird reason it's spitting an error

```
x = Symbol("x")
y = Symbol("y")

f = x*y
f = lambdify(x, y, f)
print(f(3, 3))
```

If I try to do the same thing with a single variable function instead it'll work as it should but when I try to run this same code with multivariable inputs I get an error like this

> TypeError: Argument must be either a string, dict or module but it is:
> x*y

How do I fix this? I am still very new to SymPy <-<

Comment: See [docs-of-lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/utilities/lambdify.html)

Answer (score 1):

As shown in the docs:

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html#sympy.utilities.lambdify.lambdify

```
To call a function like f(x, y) then [x, y] will
be the first argument of the lambdify:

>>> f = lambdify([x, y], x + y)
>>> f(1, 1)
2
```

Answer (score 0):

Function could either be constructed explicitly or as symbol but not as you did. This `f = x*y` is a mathematical expression see code:

```
import  sympy as sp

x, y = sp.symbols('x y')

# function
f = sp.symbols('f', cls=sp.Function)
f_eval = f(x, y)
print(f_eval.subs(x, 2))

# expression
expr = sp.Expr(x*y)
print(expr.subs(x, 3))

# lambdify
f = sp.lambdify(args=[x, y], expr=x*y)
print(f(2, 3))
```

Output

```
f(2, y)
Expr(3*y)
6
```

Comment: `Error_m = a_ns2*m**2 - b_ns(n)*m + b_ns2(n)
  Error_prime = Error_m.diff(m)
  Error_m = lambdify(m, Error_m)
  Error_prime = lambdify(m, Error_prime)`

Doesn't using lambdify here like this work?

Comment: @Madhav Krishna I don't know the reason why you need to use `lambdify`... in case here the docs with examples https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html?highlight=lambdify#module-sympy.utilities.lambdify

Comment: @Madhav Krishna updated. Anyway is quite ambiguous your question, function or lambdify are not the same